# Pixely fonts and shapes for iOS project in Flash CS5

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, flash-cs5

I created a hello world project in Flash CS5 (Windows 7) for iPhone, but everything looks pixely.
[image]

I set resolution to 960x640 and test device is iPhone 4. Can I fix this?

Comment: I think Flash CS5 doesn't support retina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the Retina display resolution was added into Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5. When publishing, go to File > AIR for iOS Settings. You will have a “Resolution” drop-down menu where you can choose between the options of “Standard” and “High” (Retina). Unfortunately (from what I’ve read), this will not be a feature in Flash versions prior to CS5.5; You *will* need to upgrade to use this feature.